# Logical Operation On a Few Columns Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a column in Pandas that looks to see whether any of the columns in the selected set of columns have a False value in them.

| Index | Item 1 Truth | Item 1 Value | Item 2 Truth | Item 2 Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | True | 65 | True | 10 |
| Second | False | 50 | True | 55 |

There are a lot more than 2 of the "Truth" columns so list comprehension etc. would be very helpful here. The output for Row 1 should be True and the output for Row 2 should be false. I have so far tried using `.apply` and `all()` etc. but nothing seems to be working so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `.filter` the dataframe and the use `.all()` with `axis=1` (rows):

```py
df["result"] = df.filter(regex=r"Truth$").all(axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    Index  Item 1 Truth  Item 1 Value  Item 2 Truth  Item 2 Value  result
0   First          True            65          True            10    True
1  Second         False            50          True            55   False
```